# Xamarin iOS Tool exited with code1: Output: ditto: Can't get real path for source

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I added a Notification Service Extension project to my Xamarin project. Then I added a reference to it in the Xamarin main iOS project. When building i get this error:

**Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   Tool exited with code: 1. Output: ditto: can't get real path for source '../../NotifServiceExtension/ac83d35a0ee368097132b3463a52c5b0/bin/iPhone/Debug/NotifServiceExtension.appex' SARR1.iOS**

Any ideas please?

Comment: Try to remove Notification Service Extension and add it again

Comment: @LucasZ it worked. Even though I tried it once before. I did it more times and it worked. Thanks!

Comment: Can you mark my answer? So that other developer can find answer easilier when they have similar question

Comment: @LucasZ I had to remove the reference again, because the extension does not work in Debug mode, so I needed to debug the host app. When I added the extension project reference to the host app again i get the same error when building. I do not know how I got it to work last time but the only thing I did i think is remove and re-add. I checked whether the settings of both ios projects the host and the extension are the same in ther plists, including targets etc. Right now I cant get it to compile without the error.

Answer (score 7):

Please check if the flag `<DeviceSpecificBuild>` is set to `true` in the extension project for the configuration you are trying to build. If it is, change the flag to `false`. Now the app build should succeed, with the extension included.

Comment: in addition, i needed to disable device specific builds in my main project. i then had to restart VS. cleaning the project and reconnecting to the Mac build agent was not enough.

Comment: well hello, self. it looks like this crap is still happening. however, following the migration to MAUI, `DeviceSpecificBuild` isn't a thing anymore. i'm not sure what took its place, and there are several open bugs about this issue.

Answer (score 2):

Try to remove Notification Service Extension and add it again

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out.

Like @LucasZ said, **remove the reference to the iOS app extension** (in my case Notification Service Extension) from the host iOS project **WHEN** you want to **build the project in DEBUG mode**.

**Add the iOS Extension reference** to the host iOS Xamarin iOS project **when you build in RELEASE mode**.

For some reason you cant have the iOS project reference an iOS Extension project when you build in DEBUG mode. It will give the above error as of the current version of Visual Studio with Xamarin.

When in RELEASE mode, make sure you start the project with "without debugging".

Comment: This is not a solution. It's a workaround. I hate that Xamarin can't figure out simple things like this. Developing an iOS project with Xamarin is a pain in the arse.

Comment: That's totally crap indeed! How do I debug the extension then at all?!