# Cannot debug Xamarin iOS app when using a notification service extension

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I've set up a notification service extension for my Xamarin.iOS app using VS2019 on Windows. The problem is I cannot debug my application anymore because I keep getting a `"ditto" exited with code 1` error. If I change my configuration to Release mode, then everything works, but there is an issue with the Debug mode. How can I continue debugging my application?

Comment: Hi ,in debug mode ,  you should have a check the Provisioning Profiles whehter be develop certification.

Comment: Also can have a look at this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vpXOy.png).

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT Both of my provisioning profiles (one for the container app and one for the service extension) are for Development, but I'm still getting the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You should use developer certificate ( Development Provisioning Profile ) if you want to install the applications using XCode - mostly when developing.

Comment: I can install the app on my device fine. This issue is happening only when the notification service extension is present. I have two provisioning profiles. Both are for development.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what worked for me:

Clean solution, close visual studio, delete bin/obj folders then rebuild.

Switch to debug configuration, then switch your provisioning profile from manual to automatic.

Hope this works for you too.

Comment: I switched to automatic provisioning, and I'm still getting the error.

Comment: have you tried removing the referencing then readded it again?

Comment: The problem with auto provisioning is it creates a wildcard provisioning profile (`VS: Wildcard Development`) and uses the same profile for both the container app and the extension. I've read many times that two different profiles must be created for the extension to work. Also, I did remove and add the reference again, but it didn't change anything.

Comment: have you tried the solution in this thread? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52212557/xamarin-ios-tool-exited-with-code1-output-ditto-cant-get-real-path-for-sourc

Comment: I have been doing what is described in https://stackoverflow.com/a/52264666/246392. This was my workaround already, but it's very annoying because most of the time I need to run in DEBUG mode for development.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the solution, select Options - Configurations - Configuration Mappings and check that in the configuration you want to use, the extension is selected with the right target configuration, hopefully a Debug one.